# spring security Test case to perform basic authentication

Tags: junit, spring-security

I have a Junit test case, where I am authenticating to the application using

```
 public static MockHttpServletRequestBuilder prepare(
            final MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request,
            final Participant user)
    {
        return request.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .with(user(user.getAccount().getUsername())
                        .authorities(user.getAccount().getRole().getAuthorities()));
    }
```

Thing is according to the documentation provided at 
https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/23/preview-spring-security-test-web-security , It doesn't actually authenticate using username and password but It just configures SecurityContext based on the authorities that we pass.

In my case, I am logging an event whenever user logs in to application. And I want to write a test case to check whether event is being stored when the user logs into the application or not. But as spring security doesn't even authenticate the user, It is not actually calling

`onSuccessfulAuthentication(final javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, final javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response, final Authentication authResult)`

of `BasicAuthenticationFilter` where I am logging the event.

Is there any way to simulate the test case with my requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for this. Here is the code

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;  

@Test
public void testcase1(){
    MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context)
                        .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
                        .build();
    final MvcResult mvcResult = this.mvc
                    .perform(get("/").with(httpBasic("test1","password")))
                    .andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andReturn();
}
```

and I have added a CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter (where I override the onSuccessfulAuthentication method of BasicAuthenticationFilter) to my spring security configuration file.

Refer [Spring Security Token based Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354138/spring-security-token-based-authentication) for the configuration class and CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter