# Spring Security With Custom Filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I created a custom filter that fetches a token and then populates the authentication object with the token-related roles

```
@Component
public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Autowired
    private IAMUserDAO iamUserDAO;
    @Autowired
    CDBUserProfileDao cdbUserProfileDao;
    @Autowired
    IAMOAuth2Dao iamOAuth2DAO;

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TokenAuthenticationFilter.class.getCanonicalName());

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        final HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        final String accessToken = httpRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        logger.info("Request with token " + accessToken + " intercepted for rba purpose");

        if (!StringUtil.isBlank(accessToken)) {
            ResponseEntity<String> tokenResponse = Utils.validateAccessToken(httpRequest, iamOAuth2DAO);
            if (tokenResponse.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
                try {
                    UserProfiles userProfileResponse = cdbUserProfileDao.getCDBUserProfile(tokenResponse.getBody());
                    if (userProfileResponse != null) {
                        String action = iamUserDAO.getFbiFederatedAction(userProfileResponse.getEntid(),
                                userProfileResponse.getRoles().getRole());
                        if (!StringUtil.isBlank(action)) {
                            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Arrays.asList(action.split(",")).stream()
                                    .map(s -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
                            final User user = new User("", "", true, true, true, true, authorities);
                            final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                    user, null, user.getAuthorities());
                            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("rba processing encounter an error " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        logger.info("Exiting rba filter with token " + accessToken);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

I then added that filter to a springsecuritycontext as followed:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new TokenAuthenticationFilter());
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Implementing Token based authentication in this filter
        http.addFilterBefore(new TokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/calendar/search", "/calendar/v2/search")
                .access("hasRole('use-calendar') or hasRole('admin')").anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

The application existed already and I just try to add the spring security layer. The spring security version is 4.2.3. After days trying to implement this, the `TokenAuthenticationFilter` is not loaded and consequently no request is filtered. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Security Token based Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354138/spring-security-token-based-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Since the application already existed before adding the Spring Security layer, I had to add the filter in the web.xml file in the below manner:

```
     <filter>
        <filter-name>tokenAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.mycompany.authenticateb.config.TokenAuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>tokenAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```