# Introduce token login in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm developing a web service with Spring Boot and I've got some questions related to Spring Security and logins.

Currently, I maintain a table of Users, for each one persisting username, encrypted password, email and some other data.

I want to let users access several web methods using Http Basic Auth.

Thinking on the future, an android application will connect to that web service and users will login through there. So the first time a users logs in, their credentials should be stored somewhere (shared preferences, db...). My common sense says that isn't a good idea.

Best use case comes to my mind is related to the usage of tokens. A token could be given by the login web method, and only once should be credentials transmitted over the network. That token could be stored anywhere.

I've heard about JWT and OAUTH 1/2 and I've read some tutorials, but I don't know how to carry out that process nor how to integrate it with my existing Users. Perhaps this can't be done, but I wish I could, for instance storing tokens related to users.

I'll update my question later.

Thank you!

Comment: This might help...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354138/spring-security-token-based-authentication    or this  http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Spring-Security-with-Token-Based-Authentication

Comment: First of, it IS possible in Spring, though not directly supported. What you have to do is a) if a user logs in, convert the `Principal` into a JWT and send this JWT back to the client (preferrably in the HTML header) and b) configure your resources to use a JWT (sent e.g. in HTML header) for authentication. For the second part, I think you need some kind of interceptor to pull the JWT from the html header and convert it into a `Principal` understood by Spring.

Comment: @Turing85 I've to update my question and I'll explain why. I don't want my WS to provide some kind of HTML login page, registrations should be done using other applications (android, web based). That is, this web service should be lightweight and not providing web pages.

Comment: @russellhoff in this case, your webserver is a pure resource server. This means that you have to fulfill step b) of what I said. Your login-component still needs to cooperate with your resources w.r.t. authentication method, i.e. you need to ensure that your login- and resource-component use the same technique (e.g. JWT Tokens).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I decided to implement OAUTH2 with JWT following this guide, and the result was successful.

Further enhancements comprises social logins using Gmail, Facebook, and so on. I'll be looking documentation to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

first of all if you need to understand how jwt works ,this [link](https://jwt.io/) explains exactly how it works,second if you want to implement jwt based authentication using spring boot u can refer this github  [project](https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo) ,in this project the jwt based authentication is done using the spring data security