# Spring Security with custom Token authentication

Tags: java, spring, authentication, jpa, spring-security

I've been struggling in having Spring-security run well with my authentication workflow.

Here's my (JPA) entity model :

[image: Here's how authentication data is stored in database.]

I set up a token endpoint (/tokens) which is meant to receive this request object through a POST request :

[image]

The response will return an object (TokenDTO) :

[image]

The latter contains some Token's fields encrypted in a String which is meant to be sent in the Authorization header for the user to be authenticated.

Which object should implement org.springframework.security.core.Authentication ?

org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider.authenticate() accepts an Authentication implementation but returns one as well, as what I have written above it should return a TokenDTO and accept a TokenCreation, should it not ?

How should I implement the "post-tokens" endpoint ?

By the way, I use XML configuration with pre-post-annotation enabled.

Comment: Are you implementing a role based security or permission based ?

Comment: @AjitSoman yes, I am, User class implements Principal interface

Comment: You can checkout this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354138/spring-security-token-based-authentication