# Implementing user authentication in Spring MVC rest api

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, restful-authentication, spring-rest

I have built a basic crud spring mvc rest api and would like to add basic authentication for validating the user and adding login and logout. I have found a tutorial which covers spring mvc.

I have tried implementing the basic authentication and the code is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    UserBuilder users = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser(users.username("marie").password("yourmarie").roles("USER"));
}
```

With the above code it provides authentication but when the credentials are invalid it returns an exception. Instead, I would like some sort of jason or message to be returned if possible so that I can process actions in the front end based off the returned value.

One the other hand if I try to access the endpoints without authentication, it gives me a login form. Here, I would like a response too.

Also, would like to add logout functionality as well.

Please guide.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you found an exception, while invalid credentials, then simply catch the exception in your controller. and create your own authentication exception and throw it with proper message.

catch (Exception ae) {
  throw new AuthenticationException("Invalid credentials");
}



For logout you need to remove the token from the storage(memory)


You can check token in request as below
if (StringUtils.hasText(httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization"))) {
 String access_token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
}

Comment: @ColinShah Thanks for the guidance. However, now I get cors error: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request. I have added @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8585") for the api method as I am calling it from localhost:8585. Still, I get the error.

Comment: try to configure http.cors in SecurityConfig.. 
https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

Comment: I have added @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.cors();
 } in my security config and the error is gone however, I do get the results even when I send incorrect username or password.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354138/spring-security-token-based-authentication

Comment: @ColinShah I am new to this. Therefore, I am looking for basic auth only. The link provided uses token as well.

Comment: please check this. it is simplest one: https://www.baeldung.com/java-config-spring-security

Comment: @ColinShah I was aware of the above implementation and got stuck with the cors error. However, It all got resolved by adding http.cors().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic(); in the security config. Thanks for all your guidance, I really appreciate it. Could you also put your first answer as an answer so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you found an exception, while invalid credentials, then simply catch the exception in your controller. and create your own authentication exception and throw it with proper message.

> catch (Exception ae) { throw new AuthenticationException("Invalid
>   credentials"); }

For logout you need to remove the token from the storage(memory) You can check token in request as below if

> (StringUtils.hasText(httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization"))) {
>   String access_token = request.getHeader("Authorization"); }

https://www.baeldung.com/java-config-spring-security